# Linux installation won't boot due to GRUB "no such device" error

Tags: linux, boot, partitioning, grub2

I think I've exhausted all I know to do, so I'm sending up the flares. I'll try to cover it all (albeit, in pieces), so please be patient.

I decided to install Linux Mint 11 where I previously had Ubuntu 10.10. Before this install, I had a partition with Windows XP, which--at some time in the distant past--I used to dual boot into. I removed the partition in this install.

After installation, the system fails to boot. After the check for a CD/DVD, it prints:

```
error: no such device: xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx
GRUB rescue>
```

There were no problems booting Ubuntu. I seem to recall a similar issue last time I did an install (instead of an upgrade) to Ubuntu. It's been a while, but I thought I fixed it using `FIXMBR` and/or `FIXBOOT` from the XP CD. Those did not work this time.

The `GRUB rescue>` prompt seems to be broken. Even `help` doesn't work. I am able to `ls`, which yields:

```
GRUB rescue> ls
(hd0) (hd0,msdos1) (hd1) (hd1,msdos1) (hd2) (hd2,msdos5) (hd2,msdos3) (hd2,msdos2) (hd2,msdos1)
```

Further, I don't know what this device is. I can't find a matching UUID under `/dev/disk/by-uuid`. For that matter, there are no UUIDs for my booting hard drive (sda, below). My setup is a Frankenbox. I know not to rely on device enumeration in such a mix, but they're given below for easy discussion.

- Ch 0 Master: 250GB PATA (sda)

  - sda1
- Ch 0 Slave: none
- Ch 1 Master: 80GB SATA (sdb)

  - sdb1: /
  - sdb2: /home
  - sdb3: swap
- Ch 1 Slave: DVD SATA
- SATA expansion card: 250GB SATA (sdc)

  - sdc1

I thought I'd struck gold when I discovered some lingering (and confounding) RAID metadata on sda. The drive hadn't shown up in the Linux install before, but did after using `dmraid -r -E /dev/sda`. However, the boot failure persisted.

Until just now, I could use the Mint install CD to "Boot from Local Drive", which would indeed take me to my installation on sdb1. After using the CD to boot to the drive, and running the below, I've worsened the problem to giving a `GRUB>` prompt instead of booting to the drive.

```
# GRUB-install --no-floppy /dev/sdb1
# update-GRUB
GRUB> find /boot/GRUB/stage1
GRUB> root (hd1,0) # result of above
GRUB> setup (hd0)
```

There's definitely a mismatch, because sdb, which has 3 partitions, seems to be `(hd2)` at the `GRUB rescue>` prompt, but `(hd1)` when actually booted. However, if I've used UUIDs (and I think I have), this shouldn't be a problem. Using the live CD, I see sdb1:/boot/GRUB/menu.list to contain

```
# kopt=root=UUID=[UUID of sdb1]
...
# groot=[UUID of sdb1]
```

The root problem, as I understand it, is that GRUB is, for some reason I don't understand, trying to boot a device that doesn't exist. I don't know how to determine what it's looking for by the UUID given. I don't see any UUIDs for anything on sda.

And now, I can't even boot to the drive using the CD.

**Update:**

I thought putting the `/boot` partition on the same drive as the MBR might help, so I added sda2, set the `boot` flag, and reinstalled (which is probably overkill).

I again get the `grub rescue>` prompt, but now, when I `ls`, I get

```
grub rescue> ls
(hd0) (hd0,msdos1) (hd1) (hd1,msdos2) (hd1,msdos1) (hd2) (hd2,msdos3) (hd2,msdos2) (hd2,msdos1)
```

So, sda is no more (hd0) at this prompt than sdb is (hd1). I don't know why it's so misaligned, nor why it matters. I may try again, putting `/boot` on sdc/(hd0).

Comment: Could you explain your edit, @studiohack? I wrote the grub prompts in lowercase, as that's how they appear onscreen. Further, /boot/GRUB/menu.list is most certainly an invalid path, as the Linux filesystem is case-sensitive.

Comment: my apologies, that was an automatic correction when I edited out the 'thanks'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was just to put the GRUB loader (MBR?) on the correct drive. In this case, what loaded in Linux as /dev/sdc and (hd2) loaded in GRUB as (hd0).

Comment: how? could you please elaborate?

Comment: Ha, no, not 5 years later.

Comment: haha no worries.. the solution by @Damon worked for me.. but thanks anyway

Answer (score 4):

I got the same error due to an ill marked UUID in the bootloader and [This guy](http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?f=17&t=84704%20%22This%20guy) had the answer for me along with [these available commands](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Troubleshooting) in grub recover mode.

Essentially first, you need to identify the drive and partition that has the grub menu files typically located in /boot/grub

```
ls [to identify your drive and partition options]
ls (hdx,p)/ [to identify which partition has the /boot folder]
```

Then, you can load the boot menu manually from the drive and partition you found above.

```
set prefix="(hdx,p)/boot/grub"
set root="(hdx,p)"
insmod normal
normal
```

In my case, I modified the UUID of our boot drive manually and purposefully, updated the grub menu and fstab, but forgot to load a new bootloader to update the UUID and/or drive in the bootloader.  Then, the drives were not in the order expected in grub and the above took care of it all; it got the menu back so I could get back in and update the bootloader with the new UUID information

Comment: As a note, I was moving disks again and no matter what I did I could not seem to get the boot loader to point to the UUID of the new disk even though grub.cfg had all new UUIDs.  The easiest solution was to boot from the new disk with the OP error, run through manually booting via the above, then running through "grub-mkconfig", then "update-grub", then "grub-install /dev/newdisk" in the OS running from the new disk.

Comment: Thank you for guiding us through this atrocious Grub syntax (`insmod normal`, wow...), with these [magic commands](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/html_node/normal.html "GNU GRUB Manual 2.02: normal") I was able to boot this machine again :-)

Comment: This works great, however, I have to do this every single restart.... even after the new grub install

Answer (score -2):

Just use the [Boot-Repair-Disk](http://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair-cd/home/Home/) utility. It worked great for me.

Comment: Could you perhaps [edit] your post and explain how exactly to use it?