# grub rescue, OS not booting

Tags: linux, windows-10, boot, fedora

When I boot my computer I get this:

```
error: no such device: 6ae62c89-5573-4c83-b4b8-9aa3722bd1f8.
error: unknown filesystem.
Entering rescue mode...
grub rescue>
```

Background:

I installed Fedora 26 and then Windows 10 on another partition.
After then installation of Windows, the system was booting directly on Windows without the option of Fedora.

I used the same Fedora live CD to run a virtual environment and run the following commands on a terminal:

```
fdisk -l
grub2-install /dev/sda
grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg
```

Any idea how to fix it?

Comment: The order I typically use is "grub-mkconfig", then "update-grub", then "grub-install /dev/disk".. Also verify your UUIDs match in grub.cfg vs blkid.

Comment: In the future, I think the general consensus is install windows first; ALWAYS.  Windows kills anything it can, so if you install it first, it (windows) cannot "kill" anything.  Linux is happy to play with other OS's.

Comment: This answer https://superuser.com/questions/359417/linux-installation-wont-boot-due-to-grub-no-such-device-error/791825#791825 might be helpful, although only loosely related to your Q's.